# Google Site Search fails to return results

Tags: google-search, google-sites, google-search-api

This code was working about 2 months ago. I understand it is deprecated, but it was working fine a few months ago like early October(2013). Did Google change their API again?

```
google.load('search', '1');

function OnLoad() {
  // Create a search control
  var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

  // Add in a WebSearch
  var webSearch = new google.search.WebSearch();

  // Restrict our search to pages from the Cartoon Newtowrk
  webSearch.setSiteRestriction('stmikes.utoronto.ca');

  // Add the searcher to the SearchControl
  searchControl.addSearcher(webSearch);

  // tell the searcher to draw itself and tell it where to attach
  searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("content"));

  // execute an inital search
  searchControl.execute('SMC');
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">Loading...</div>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

It's [deprecated and rate-limited](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/). You should use Google Custom Search instead.